# why the button not display (minus button which in on header)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I am trying to make same thing which is in this example
http://plnkr.co/edit/aFa2LyH555o3mho7nRq7?p=preview
.In given example there is one header having **(-)** sign in left top .But when I use same code it doesn't display the minus button .could you please tell me how to display that minus button

Here is my code
https://dl.dropbox.com/s/l2dtrxmnsurccxt/www.zip?dl=0

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Todo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="css/ionic.min.css" />
    <script  src="lib/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

 <body ng-app="app">
 <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
     <button class="button button-icon icon ion-ios7-minus-outline"
             ng-click=""></button>
     <h1 class="title">TODO Tasks</h1>

     <button class="button button-icon ion-arrow-move"
             ></button>
 </ion-header-bar>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle so we can see it in action to be able to edit

Comment: ^ Yes, a zip isn't the best.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney actually fiddle show error .it show limit is exceed

Comment: @TonyBarnes it is onl reproduceable when you run index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS version and icon name you're using seem to be outdated.

If you [get the latest CSS version](http://ionicons.com/) (or via CDN)

You'll see that the class name of the icon you wish to use has changed from:

```
ion-ios7-minus-outline
```

to:

```
ion-ios-minus-outline
```

Comment: could you please check this.here is my code https://dl.dropbox.com/s/l2dtrxmnsurccxt/www.zip?dl=0

Comment: barmes please download and check.or remove your answer

Comment: @user944513 updated my answer with a working solution.